# Chrome custom tab secondary color

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm using Chrome custom tab in my app. There an intent extra to set the secondary toolbar color called EXTRA_SECONDARY_TOOLBAR_COLOR, however I can't see where this color is actually used in Chrome tab. The only color I see is the primary color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is used to set the color for the secondary toolbar, also known as the bottom toolbar (see [CustomTabsIntent.Builder#addToolbarItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.Builder.html#addToolbarItem(int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent))).

Since *API level 24.1.0*, this method of adding items for adding items to the bottom toolbar has been **deprecated** in favor of using [RemoteViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html), where you define the style in your app. Check [CustomTabsIntent.Builder#setSecondaryToolbarViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.Builder.html#setSecondaryToolbarViews(android.widget.RemoteViews,%20int[],%20android.app.PendingIntent)) for more information. There's an example on how to use it on the [Github sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsclient/MainActivity.java#L301-L305) as well.